# SQL Join Query based on value in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have two SQL tables namely employees and conditions

```
create table employees(
name varchar(100),
deptID int,
Salary int
);

insert into employees(Name, DeptID, Salary) Values 
('Raj', 1 , 27000),
('Usha', 2 , 25000),
('Vinoth', 2 , 22000),
('Ranjith', 1 , 40000),
('Jai', 1 , 45000);


create table conditions(
deptID int,
condition varchar(MAX)
);

insert into conditions(deptID, condition) Values 
(1, 'Salary > 25000; Salary < 35000'),
(2, 'Salary = 25000'),
(1, 'Salary > 35000; Salary <= 40000');
```

The Two tables join together based on the deptID

Below is the expected result

```
Result

Name            Salary              Condition
__________________________________________________________________
Raj             27000           Salary > 25000; Salary < 35000
Usha            25000               Salary = 25000
Vinoth          22000               NULL
Ranjith         40000           Salary > 35000; Salary <= 40000
Jai             45000               NULL
```

My question is How to generate a SQL query to generate the above result?

In the above result, The condition column values are displayed when the salary matches with the condtions in the condition table.

I have written this Query

```
select e.name,
   c.deptid,
   replace(replace(c.condition, 'Salary', e.salary), ';', ' and') result
   from employees e left join conditions c on e.deptid = c.deptid
   order by name, condition;
```

and the result is

```
Name     DeptID             Condition
________________________________________________
Jai             1               45000 > 25000 and 45000 < 35000
Jai             1               45000 > 35000 and 45000 <= 40000
Raj             1               27000 > 25000 and 27000 < 35000
Raj             1               27000 > 35000 and 27000 <= 40000
Ranjith         1               40000 > 25000 and 40000 < 35000
Ranjith         1               40000 > 35000 and 40000 <= 40000
Usha            2               25000 = 25000
Vinoth          2               22000 = 25000
```

Now i am not sure how to evaluate the condition column to get true or false result. Can someone help by adding the condtion to query ??

Comment: Consider storing conditions in a more-normalized form. E.g. dept_id,condition_lower_limit,condition_upper_limit

Comment: Don't tag four database servers but only one

Comment: The only way I could see to do this would be with Dynamic SQL (which would in effect generate the case statement); or hard-codding the conditions in a case statement.  or use a function and some sort of evaluate statement on the condition and salary.

Comment: @xQbert You mean without fixing the broken data model !??!

Comment: Consider changing "Condition" to two columns "SalarayMin" and "SalaryMax"

Comment: @Strawberry Likely would need to correct data model if we really want a data driven system.  Technically we could do this without changing the data model  by separating out the; into separate lines assuming "AND" but that seems like so much overhead and such a bad design. Better to fix data model first if using Dynamic SQL.  If using a hardcoded case statement or function then data model doesn't need to be fixed; provided conditions don't grow; or we update functions/case statement when it does.  But then it's not a data driven system.  My assumption would be fix the structure, but assumption.

Comment: I've removed the MySQL tag because `condition varchar(MAX)` isn't valid MySQL code

Comment: What is the background - is this a production system an organization is using in real life? I often side with developers/DBA's who have little control over what's in place and have to play the hand they are dealt. But this kind of database arrangement is where even I would draw the line. If the organization wasn't willing to change it, I would not accept a job with them.

Comment: Don't store values in such column. Only Show it while displaying in UI application or report by writing the logic using `CASE` expression etc.

Comment: @Strawberry Say I have stored this into two separate columns as you said. But the condition will not be always < and  >. But can also be  <=, >=, ==, !=. And it is always not that there will be only two conditions it can also be only one sometimes like salary =25000. Now for this how to Write a SQL Query?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like query is for SQL server because there is no values clause or varachar datatype in Oracle.

But if you want to evaluate boolean expressions in Oracle you can use XML features.

```
with employees(Name, DeptID, Salary) as 
(select 'Raj', 1, 27000 from dual
union all select 'Usha', 2 , 25000 from dual
union all select 'Vinoth', 2, 22000 from dual
union all select 'Ranjith', 1, 40000 from dual
union all select 'Jai', 1, 45000 from dual)
, conditions(deptID, condition) as 
(select 1, 'Salary > 25000; Salary < 35000' from dual
union all select 2, 'Salary = 25000' from dual
union all select 1, 'Salary > 35000; Salary <= 40000' from dual)
select e.*,
       c.*,
       xmlquery(replace(replace(condition, 'Salary', salary), ';', ' and') returning content) result
  from employees e left join conditions c on e.deptid = c.deptid
 order by name, condition;

NAME        DEPTID     SALARY   DEPTID_1 CONDITION                       RESULT   
------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------------- ---------
Jai              1      45000          1 Salary > 25000; Salary < 35000  false    
Jai              1      45000          1 Salary > 35000; Salary <= 40000 false    
Raj              1      27000          1 Salary > 25000; Salary < 35000  true     
Raj              1      27000          1 Salary > 35000; Salary <= 40000 false    
Ranjith          1      40000          1 Salary > 25000; Salary < 35000  false    
Ranjith          1      40000          1 Salary > 35000; Salary <= 40000 true     
Usha             2      25000          2 Salary = 25000                  true     
Vinoth           2      22000          2 Salary = 25000                  false    

8 rows selected
```

For more complex logic there is (was) Rule Manager.

[Desupport of Database Rules Manager (RUL) and Expression Filter (EXF)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/deprecated.htm#UPGRD60127)

Comment: Thank You, I got some idea to work out, but stuck with the last step to the get result